# NSDate -dateFromString returns nil

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting nil from the date formatter. `originTime` is 2011-08-25 02:12:59, and I believe `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` is the correct format for that. What is my mistake?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
assert(locale != nil);
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[dateFormat setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *od = [dateFormat dateFromString:originTime]; // nil
```

Comment: [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss"];try like this

Comment: no vijay the format is correct the 2 lines after that is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the `setDateStyle` and `setTimeStyle` methods. You are specifying the format on your own (with `setDateFormat`).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know they were mutually exclusive.